# Facebook iOS SDK - creating user owned objects and publishing an open graph story without a backend server

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6

My goal is to achieve something along the lines of this without implementing a backend web server:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjA21.png]

currently, I am using this code:

```
id<FBOpenGraphAction> _action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];

_action[@"book"] = @{
                   @"type":@"books.book",
                   @"fbsdk:create_object": @YES,
                   @"title":@"test title 1",
                   @"url":@"http://test-test.test",
                   @"image":@"http://www.m5zn.com/uploads/2010/7/15/photo/071510030742woekhs48rdt1ifcwp.jpg",

                   @"description": @"development in progress - test description",
                   @"data": @{@"isbn":@"0-316-31696-2"}
                   };


[FBSettings enableBetaFeature:FBBetaFeaturesOpenGraphShareDialog];


[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction:_action
                                      actionType:@"books.reads"
                             previewPropertyName:@"book"
                                         handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                             if(error) {
                                                 NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                             } else {
                                                 NSLog(@"Success!");
                                             }
                                         }];
```

Nothing is being logged when that code is run. Additionally, here is the AppDelegate fragment:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    // attempt to extract a token from the url


    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication withSession:FBSession.activeSession fallbackHandler:^(FBAppCall *call) {
        DLog(@"in fallback handler");
    }];

    // return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];

}
```

I attempted to follow this example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mLuaUtbGvEM#at=322
Found at the end of this article: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/

Yet the share dialogue does not come up, and nothing is logged in the console. 
What went wrong? Are there some dependencies that I'm missing? Is my view controller not complying with certain protocols? Are certain handlers not invoked? W

What is additionally necessary to get this to work?

Comment: What version of the Facebook app do you have?

Comment: Using the newest facebook SDK as of right now, 3.5

Comment: Not the SDK, but the Facebook app. The presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction method requires the Facebook app to be present on device in order to work. You can call the corresponding canPresent method to check whether the Facebook app is available, and if it supports the method.